# Driver not Found PDO mysqli

Tags: php, pdo

estoy intentado utilizar PDO
Utilizo Windows 10, php 7.4.2 y XAMPP

```
$base = new PDO("mysqli:host=localhost; dbname=test, 'root','' ");
```

Y recibo el siguiente error
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso\pdo.php:2 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso\pdo.php(2): PDO->__construct('mysqli:host=loc...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso\pdo.php on line 2

He ido al archivo php.ini y he ingresado la siguiente linea extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll ya que no lo tenia, y me sigue sin ir, el DLL lo tengo en la carpeta EXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es por que no lleva la 'i' en mysql

```php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

Te recomiendo [esta página](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) a mí me ayudó mucho para hacer la conección a la base de datos y hacer consultas

Comment: Vale gracias, probé mysql y me daba otro error.. Debia tener en las comillas, ahora me va con mysql, gracias